# Simple LINQ and List error: WhereListIterator`1[Task]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Task]'

Tags: asp.net, linq, code-behind

I'm having trouble understanding my error

Method:

```
public List<Task> GetAllTasks()
{
    var AllTasks = from t in tasks
                   where t.Status.ToString() == "Completed" || t.Status.ToString() == "Pending"
                   select t;

    return (List<Task>)AllTasks;
}
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TaskList tdl = (TaskList)Session["TodoList"];
    List<Task> AllTasks = tdl.GetAllTasks();
    string str = "";

    foreach (Task t in AllTasks)
    {
        str += t.ToString() + "<br />";
    }

    LblTasks.Text = str;

}
```

After I add a task (AddTask.aspx) I redirect to another page to display them, then I get the runtime error:

Unable to cast object of type 'WhereListIterator`1[Task]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Task]'.

Is there something wrong with my LINQ? I just learned yesterday hehe.

Thanks.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You just need a `.ToList()` either directly on the query or when you return it. As in

```
var AllTasks = (from t in tasks
               where t.Status.ToString() == "Completed" || t.Status.ToString() == "Pending"
               select t).ToList();
```

Or

```
return AllTasks.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks alot! That works. 

I see the point of ToList(), but how come the typical cast doesn't work?

Comment: @Ken, The LINQ querying methods are designed to work against any sequence implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, and they are lazily evaluated. The source being a `List<T>` isn't relevant. If you want concrete collections, they have provided methods to support that, such as `ToArray(), ToList(), ToDictionary(),` etc.