# EF MVC Core filtering a list is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a PostgreSQL query which is beyond the capacity of a LINQ statement as far as I know or at least I haven't been able to figure it out, so I decided I would use raw SQL. Following are the relevant code snippets.

Controller:

```html
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
        {
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.ConOrgSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "Client_desc" : "Client";
            ViewBag.AssignedSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "Assigned_desc" : "Assigned";
            ViewBag.ExpiresSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "Expires_desc" : "Expires";
            ViewBag.LastActiveSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "LastActive_desc" : "LastActive";
            ViewBag.IDSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "Id_desc" : "";

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

            var results = _context.NodeIndexViewModel.ToList();

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                results = results.Where(s => s.ContractingOrg.Contains(searchString)
                                       || s.NodeID.ToString().StartsWith(searchString));
            }

            
            int pageSize = 10;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(await results.ToPagedListAsync(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
```

NodeIndexViewModel:

```html
using NpgsqlTypes;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using static UnidAdmin.Models.Bundle;

namespace UnidAdmin.Models
{
    public class NodeIndexViewModel
    {
        public int NodeID { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public String? AssignedOrg { get; set; }
        public String? ContractingOrg { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Expiry { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMM dd,yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? LastActive { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMM dd,yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public NodeType? NodeType { get; set; }
        public String? Comment { get; set; }
        
    }
}
```

DbContext ModelBuilder:

```html
modelBuilder.Entity<NodeIndexViewModel>()
.ToSqlQuery("select DISTINCT ON(s.id) s.id as NodeID, s.name as Name, bn.node_type as NodeType, t.short_name as AssignedOrg, o.short_name as ContractingOrg, bn.end_utc as Expiry, s.active_date as LastActive, s.comment as Comment from admin.node s FULL OUTER JOIN admin.bundle_node bnn on s.id = bnn.node_id FULL OUTER JOIN admin.bundle bn on bnn.bundle_id = bn.id FULL OUTER JOIN admin.agreement ag on bn.agreement_id = ag.id FULL OUTER JOIN admin.organization o on ag.org_id = o.id JOIN admin.organization t on t.id = s.org_id order by s.id, bn.end_utc")
.HasKey(m => m.NodeID);
```

DbContext DbSet:

```html
public DbSet<NodeIndexViewModel> NodeIndexViewModel { get; set; }
```

The initial load of the View works perfectly. The View code isn't relevant because the issue is arising when trying to filter the list in the controller with the following lines of code:

```html
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
  {
    results = results.Where(s => s.ContractingOrg.Contains(searchString)
              || s.NodeID.ToString().StartsWith(searchString));
  }
```

The solution won't build and I am getting CSO266 casting error.

This is the suggested fix:

```html
results = (List<NodeIndexViewModel>)results.Where(s => s.ContractingOrg.Contains(searchString)
                                       || s.NodeID.ToString().StartsWith(searchString));
```

And this is the error message:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereListIterator`1[UnidAdmin.Models.NodeIndexViewModel]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UnidAdmin.Models.NodeIndexViewModel]'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple LINQ and List error: WhereListIterator\`1\[Task\]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List\`1\[Task\]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953748/simple-linq-and-list-error-wherelistiterator1task-to-type-system-collectio)

Comment: @CodeCaster  No it doesn't.  I have added the ToList() at the end of the results filter but the Where method is throwing weird errors claiming that Column NodeID doesn't exist when it definitely does.  When I inspect the initial result I can see it as one of the fields in the list objects.

Comment: So it does, but now you have a new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  var results = from s in _context.NodeIndexViewModel 
                 select s;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            results = results.Where(s => s.ContractingOrg.Contains(searchString)
                                   || s.NodeID.StartsWith(searchString));
        }

        
        int pageSize = 10;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(await results.OrderBy(x => something).ToPagedListAsync(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

If you use list in the initial query, that would defeat the purpose of having PageList. As it loads everything out and consume memory. If you really need to use toList() on the initial query, you will need to include to list in the filter as well. So you will need to put tolist() on the filtering.

Finally IpageList won't work without ordering. So you need to put an order in order to get the pagelist to work.

Comment: As soon as I change the var =results to your suggestion I get an error on results.where()

Comment: check properly. It is just a simple linq query.